# AJAX call to ASP page to update database record works only once in IE9

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, asp-classic

After several pieces of helpful advice from the members of this forum I'm getting closer to solving what should be a simple issue. I'm a complete newbie to AJAX.

Can someone please tell me why this piece of code works fine in Firefox 8 but not in IE 9? It works ONCE in IE but not again unless I close the browser and reopen!!??

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
    //Browser Support Code
    function ajaxFunction(){
        var ajaxRequest;
        try {
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        catch(e) {
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } 
            catch(e) {
                try {
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e){
                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
            }
        }

        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "disp_processTEXT.asp", false);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
    }
//-->
</script>
```

The readystate is left blank as it is copied code which originally assigned a value to a div but I only want to run the database code in the asp page.  Presumably this could have been deleted?

The code to be run in the asp page is

```
<%
    Set MyConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    MyConn.Open "dsn=xxx;uid=xxx;password=xxx;"
        SQLString = "UPDATE dbo_tbl_printing_tempstore SET front_has_text1 = 'YES', front_text = 'help' WHERE id = 106567"
        MyConn.Execute(SQLString)
    MyConn.Close
    Set MyConn = Nothing
%>
```

Please help me as this is driving me mad.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Switch to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and its Ajax system as it should be cross browser compatable out the box, and saves you huge amounts of time:

Add a reference for jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and switch to its [Ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (place below the above):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'disp_processTEXT.asp',
          success: function(response) {
            alert('It worked');
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

### Update:

To bind to the onblur event using jQuery try this. Remove the onblur= attribute from your current code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#yourinput').on('blur', function(){        
        $.ajax({
          url: 'disp_processTEXT.asp',
          success: function(response) {
            alert('It worked');
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qmPLj/

Comment: akiller - thanks for your reply.  I'll give it a try and let you know how I get on.

Comment: akiller.  I tried this  I works fine in FF but works only the first time I call it in IE9.

Comment: akiller (sorry I'm getting used to the edit s in the forum).  I tried this. I called it from an onblur="" of a textarea.  It works fine in FF8 but only works once in IE9.  It only works again in IE9 if I close and reopen the browser. Any ideas?  Also, when I left the success: alert in the code it ran in a loop, do you know why?

Comment: It might be due to how IE handles the onblur event (I don't know much about it). You could remove the onblur attribute altogether and bind jQuery to the blur event. See my changes above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It has worked for me across all browsers but some Opera versions.

```
function GetXmlHttpObject(handler)
{
     var objXmlHttp=null;
     if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")>=0)
     {
          var strName="Msxml2.XMLHTTP";
          if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 5.5")>=0)
          {
               strName="Microsoft.XMLHTTP";
          }
          try
          {
               objXmlHttp=new ActiveXObject(strName);
               objXmlHttp.onreadystatechange=handler;
               return objXmlHttp;
          }
          catch(e)
          {
               alert("Error. Scripting for ActiveX might be disabled");
               return;
          }
     }
     else //All other browsers
     {
          objXmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          objXmlHttp.onload=handler;
          objXmlHttp.onerror=handler;
          return objXmlHttp;
     }
}

var url= "http://www.example.com/";
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject(stateChanged);
xmlHttp.open("GET", url , true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply.  I'll see if I can get this to work.